# Graph object showing error

Tags: android

Initially I was trying to display message, id, createdTime from graph API response which I did it successfully but when I tried get full picture along with these data I am getting the Error [image]

here is my code

```
           private fun getPosts() {

                 GraphRequest(
                 AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/posts ? 
                 fields=full_picture,message,id,created_time", null, 
                 HttpMethod.GET,
                 GraphRequest.Callback { response ->
                    Log.e(TAG, response.toString())
                      var jsonResponse:JSONObject=  response.getJSONObject()
                    // JSONObject(response.toString())
                        var jsonArray:JSONArray=jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data")
                  //  Toast.makeText(this,"Size here is"+ jsonArray.length() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length())
                        {
                           var  insidata:JSONObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            if (insidata.has( "message")) {
                                 mMessage  = insidata.getString("message")
                                allMessage?.add(mMessage as String)
                            }
                            if (insidata.has("id")) {

                                 mIdd = insidata.getString("id")
                                allId?.add(mIdd as String)
                            }
                            if (insidata.has("created_time")) {
                                 dateOfCreation = insidata.getString("created_time")
                                allCreatedDate?.add(dateOfCreation.toString())
                            }
                     /*       if (i==0) {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "" + mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                            */
                        }
        //            Toast.makeText(this, "" + allMessage.size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



                  //  }

                 //   catch (e: JSONException)
                  //  {
                    //    e.printStackTrace()
                   // }


                }

        ).executeAsync()

                  GraphRequest(
                 AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/posts", null, 
                 HttpMethod.GET,
                 GraphRequest.Callback { response ->
```

when I tried this it was working perfectly. Now I want to add Pictures as well.

Comment: Acronym capitalization; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
       var parameterss:Bundle =  Bundle()
        parameterss.putString("fields","full_picture,message,id,created_time")
        request.parameters =parameterss
        request.executeAsync()
```

Bundle class that i could  have  iplimented but... . Mistake by a Beginner